# Indefinite article before "given" in "We should consider it a given that no one thought Pavlik Morozov a hero in his lifetime"

Tags: articles, indefinite-article, nominalization

> We should consider it **a given** that no one thought Pavlik Morozov a hero in his lifetime.

([Source](https://books.google.cz/books?id=RQocp14-tMIC&pg=PT119&lpg=PT119&dq=pavlik%20morozov%20myth&source=bl&ots=j_fH2KWOPl&sig=YNz46O3lOggrxeZEOnrPZAR5Y-s&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAzgKahUKEwixw9TtzI3JAhUBvhQKHU-XCyU#v=onepage&q=pavlik%20morozov%20myth&f=false))

What kind of the part of speech is "given" in the sentence? I suppose it is the adjective and the presence of the indefinite article after it is because the noun (probably "fact") is intentionally omitted. Am I right?

Comment: It's probably "a [nominalized adjective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominalized_adjective)", or "an adjective nominalized through [zero-derivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_(word_formation))".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We should consider it **a given** that no one thought Pavlik Morozov a hero in his lifetime.

Since it has an article, it **can't be an adjective**.  It is **a noun** in your sentence.  See, for instance, the definition '2' in [Merriam-Webster dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/given).

Comment: The fancy linguistic term for't is probably "[nominalized adjective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominalized_adjective)". (0: